# Print Avery Label from Java, need template standards

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I want to print Avery Labels from Java.

What are all the template standards (size, margin...) for all the Avery Labels?

Comment: You can find them all (2248 of them) at http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-%26-Software/Templates/Labels/?Ns=Rank&Rpp=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [WorldLabel website](http://www.worldlabel.com/Pages/template_1.htm). They have all of the label templates in ms-word, pdf and open office. You have to download them one by one, which is rather inconvenient. But if you are in a rush it's an option.